# Kubernetes, specify network and health check

Tags: stellar-core, docker

I'm trying to run Stellar in Kubernetes.

Initially I'm working with the quickstart (`stellar/quickstart:latest`).

The problem I'm facing is, when specifying the network via an explicit `command` and `args` then the `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` fail.

## Probes

When I do NOT specify a command, and arg, it starts fine, using `testnet`.

However, when I *do* try to specify the command and arg - so that I can use `pubnet` -  I get the below error:

```
      containers:
        - name: chain-node
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: {{ .Values.image }}
          command: ["start"]
          args: ["--pubnet"]
```

## When it works

If I do NOT specify a command and arg, then the container starts, and the probes run as expected.

```
      containers:
        - name: chain-node
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: {{ .Values.image }}
```

## Error

```
Liveness probe failed: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "stellar-core http-command 'info'": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

The start command is actually `/start` (with a slash) and since that is also the images default you can leave it out at all.

```
  containers:
  - name: chain-node
    image: stellar/quickstart:latest
    args: ["--pubnet"]
```